# Правильное обновления списка пользователей онлайн

Tags: php

Я вывожу всех пользователей онлайн :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo "<br>";
 echo $row['username'];
}
```

А как теперь обновлять этот список?

Comment: knes, не закрывай , с того ответа мне ничего не понятно, и к тому же у моих локациях нет id

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду ? мыслей ваших читать никто не умеет )

Comment: O_o в смысле?<br>
Если вы об обновлении без перезагрузки то аяксом естественно...

Comment: Ну вот смотрите, Есть пользователи на локации, и их нужно вывести, я вывожу, но если они выходят нужно обновить список =)

Comment: у вас в логике чего-то явно не зватает.. как вы определяете что пользователи зашли ?

Comment: Нужна работа с сессиями, в логике действительно мягко говоря чего-то не хватает ^^

Comment: они в session запоминаются, и потом когда они заходят они видят весь список пользователей в онлайн =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в таблице Users должны обязательно быть поля :
 1. online - поле отвечает -в игре юзер или нет (1-в игре, 0 - не в игре)
 2. location - ссылка на локацию в который последний раз был отмечен пользователь.

Тогда запрос на выборку всех юзверов в определенной локации такой
"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE online=1 and location=".$location

Вещайте функцию на таймер которая раз в 5, 10, 20 мин (как хотите) подает Ajax запрос на сценарий и выводит всех пользователей данной локи.

Если юзвер вышел из игры - то обновляем его поле в таблице Users online=0.
Если юзвер перешел в другую локу- обновляем поле location для данного юзвера, и тут же для него делаем запрос всех пользователей находящихся в этой локе

Кк то так

Comment: Все это хорошо =) Но как в location заносить ссылку ?

Comment: Должна быть отдельная таблица списка локаций location вида:
ID|NAME
1 |Гора
2 |Город
и т. д.
А в Users.location - ставим одно из значений location.id

Comment: ага =) спасибо=)

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ - используйте jquery + ajax + setInterval (setTimeOut)

Comment: И? каким образом ajax на клиенте поможет понять какой пользователь онлайн какой нет?^^<br>
У ТСа на сервере надо логику дописывать сначала...

Comment: это самый простой способ, хотя и не самый целесообразный. Нужно постоянно производить запросы к базе данных и выяснять какой у пользователя статус

Comment: Что выяснять? Какие статусы? Не было ни слова сказанно об этом ;)

Comment: ikot вы знаете другой?^^<br>
ПОделитесь, нам очень интересно...

Comment: А не мешало бы. Ответ уже дал Ale_x по поводу статусов